# Getting the return value from a tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a simple login menu using tkinter. I need the return of a function used by a button but cannot find a solution that fits with my program. I need the return of True / False depending on the users input (works) into a variable.

```
def authenticate(ENTRIES, details):
    username, password = get_entry_values(ENTRIES)
    authenticated = details.get(username) == password
    print("Authenticated" if authenticated else "Incorrect")

    label_pos = [width / 10 * 4.8, height / 10 * 3.5]
    wrong = Label(window, text='Incorrect', background=background_colour, foreground=text_colour)
    correct = Label(window, text='Authenticated', background=background_colour, foreground=text_colour)
    if authenticated:
        wrong.destroy()
        correct.place(x=label_pos[0], y=label_pos[1])
    elif not authenticated:
        correct.destroy()
        wrong.place(x=label_pos[0], y=label_pos[1])
    return authenticated

def insert_btn_commands(ENTRIES, details):
    all_btn = [{'text': 'Submit', 'pos': [width / 10 * 7.3, height / 10 * 4.5], 'command': lambda: authenticate(ENTRIES,
                                                                                                                details)}]
    return all_btn

def create_btns(all_btn):
    BUTTONS = {}
    for i in range(len(all_btn)):
        BUTTONS[f'button{i}'] = Button(window, text=all_btn[i]['text'], command=all_btn[i]['command'])
        BUTTONS[f'button{i}'].place(x=all_btn[i]['pos'][0], y=all_btn[i]['pos'][1])
        print(BUTTONS)
    return BUTTONS


def main(details):
    ENTRIES = create_ents(all_ents)
    LABELS = create_lbls(all_lbls)

    all_btn = insert_btn_commands(ENTRIES, details)
    BUTTONS = create_btns(all_btn)

    mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be able to accomplish this with a global variable to store the result of `authenticate` (which is the function I assume you're talking about)

```
authenticated = False  # declare the variable in the global scope, default to False


def authenticate(ENTRIES, details):
    global authenticated  # give this function access to modify the value of 'authenticated'

    username, password = get_entry_values(ENTRIES)
    authenticated = details.get(username) == password
    print("Authenticated" if authenticated else "Incorrect")

    label_pos = [width / 10 * 4.8, height / 10 * 3.5]
    wrong = Label(window, text='Incorrect', background=background_colour, foreground=text_colour)
    correct = Label(window, text='Authenticated', background=background_colour, foreground=text_colour)
    if authenticated:
        wrong.destroy()
        correct.place(x=label_pos[0], y=label_pos[1])
    elif not authenticated:
        correct.destroy()
        wrong.place(x=label_pos[0], y=label_pos[1])
 #  return authenticated  
    # no need to return this value any more
    # just query the 'authenticated' variable after this function is called!
```